# How to create custom atribute set using upgradeData in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attribute-set, setup-script

I am trying to create **custom attribute set** by using **upgradeData script** in **magento 2**, but it doesn't create.

Can anyone give me an advice?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code to create custom attribute set in Magento2 programmatically

We declare the namespace of our module to avoid conflicts around multiple modules and introduce more flexibility

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;

 /*
*The below are the namespaces and and classes to be included inorder to create new custom attribute set programatically
*/

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

/*
* UpgradeDataInterface brings the ‘upgrade’ method which must be implemented
*/
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $attributeSetFactory;
    private $attributeSet;
    private $categorySetupFactory;
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory, CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory )
        {
                $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
                $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory; 
                $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory; 
        } 

 public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
 {
  $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
      /**
      *checking the current version of the module 
      *this function is implemented from  ModuleContextInterface
     */
    if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1', '<')) {

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $data = [
        'attribute_set_name' => 'Your_Custom_Attribute_Set', // define custom attribute set name here
        'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
        'sort_order' => 200,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();
    }
    }
} ?>
```